# Can I eat Rabbit Poop?

Tags: survival, food, rabbits

I know that [rabbits eat their droppings (cecotropes)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/617/do-bunnies-eat-their-droppings) and I have heard of feeding rabbit droppings to pigs.  Rabbits are vegetarians. There droppings do not have the same consistency or negative secondary factors as carnivores or omnivores (i.e. people, dogs, cats, etc). In essence rabbit poop is partially digested plant material.

In a survival situation, finding and [catching rabbits can be done,](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-prepare-a-rabbit-snare-with-minimal-tools) but it's not easy. Finding and picking up rabbit droppings, would be a lot easier.

Can a person safely eat rabbit droppings? If yes is there any nutritional value in it?

Note: this question is only about the fecal droppings NOT the cecotropes.  Cecotropes are NOT easy to find.

Comment: Nesquik would be better. Rabbits, as with many wild animals, can have tapeworms and roundworm, which would be nasty.

Comment: I very much enjoy all this survival stuff, but parasites or not, I don't think I would be willing to do this. I think I would rather eat random plants and hope they helped.

Comment: @Aaron The decisions you think you would make in a difficult situation, are not always the ones you ultimately make when you truly encounter those situations. The more you know when you get there the better actual decision you will be able to make.

Comment: Keep in mind: The rabbit droppings you easily find are the wrong ones.

Comment: @cbeleites if you are suggesting finding and eating cecotropes, that is really not an option.  The only time they touch the ground is if something is wrong.  The generally go from anus to mouth directly. cecotropes on the ground indicate a problem, and you would not want to eat them if you found them.  The only other source is from a live or recently dead healthy rabbit. In this survival situation you would probably eat the rabbit not the cecotropes.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: I'm confused now - I (mis)understood your question to be about eating the cecotropes? The real poop droppings consist of stuff a herbivore could not digest in two "rounds" of digestion (so its not just partly digested plant material - its the most indigestible plant material => probably not much that can be gained from that) plus surplus gut bacteria. I'd consider the rabbit poop as (un)promising as cow droppings (and cecotropes like the rumen content).

Comment: @cbeleites in theory there should be available nutrition in the droppings, it should only be from plants relatively safe for a mamaul to eat. There have been multiple commercial and organic farm feeding programs that feed dropping through the food chain. If you have had commercially produced meat, it mostly like was feed, droppings from other animals.  I have been looking for a good article about it, but my time is limited and have not found it yet.  But google will show you several discussions,

Comment: Sure the droppings are potential feed for some (many) species (I'm thinking insects, pigs), but that doesn't mean they are suitable feed for every species. Weak (anecdata-type) evidence against humans eating rabbit poop: my great-grandfather kept ≈ 50 rabbits for food purposes (as did many people around here). I've heard lots of tales what was edible just after 2nd world war, but rabbit (sheep, chicken) droppings did not feature in any of them. They were put out as fertilizer instead (if the pigs + chickens didn't eat them I assume).

Comment: @cbeleites pigs and people are both omnivores with very similar digestive and dietary requirements. IMHO anything a pig will eat, is probably going to be ok for a person, and will probably add food value. The point of this question is to find out, if this particular item is viable for a person.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, while there are some similarities to dietary requirement, stating that everything a pig can/will eat will be fine for humans is clearly and demonstrably wrong. I invite you to help yourself to a serving of acorns or horse chestnuts.

Answer (score 4):

There is one story of someone doing this,

> You see rabbits are animals that chew their cud. Unlike ruminant animals-cows-they don't have divisions or multiple stomachs. You see, a rabbit on first pass excretes little balls of hi-energy, vegan wrapped enzymes.  The rabbit, a few hours or days later, returns and eats round one, and on second pass thru the stomach it becomes poop. Rabbits eat their round one veggie balls and/or their neighbours. Rabbits are highly communal animals. Anyhow, with the aid of his trained eye, Grandpa and I collected and added these rabbit poops to our soup mix, one of the most enzyme rich foods known to man.

[Quick and Easy One Pot Rabbit Poop Soup](http://www.douglasmckinnonesquire.com/blog/one-pot-rabbit-poop-soup)

And supposedly rabbit poop cures hangovers, see [here](http://www.theasterisktoday.com/articles/cure-your-hangover-the-cowboy-way/) and [here](http://www.theasterisktoday.com/articles/cure-your-hangover-the-cowboy-way/).

On the other hand rabbits can get worms,

> Rabbits consuming fresh grass or greens might consume tapeworm eggs. Obeliscoides cuniculi, a stomach worm, causes appetite and weight loss if your rabbit carries a lot of them. Pinworms (Passalurus abiguus) are among the most common worms infecting bunnies. Rabbits might also pick up roundworms, or ascarids. Wild rabbits are prone to additional types of worms, but these rarely affect domestic bunnies.

[Source](https://animals.mom.me/treat-worms-rabbits-10733.html)

So it really doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: If I was browsing on forage, wouldn't I also be at risk of consuming all of these parasites directly?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Maybe, but I would guess that the parasites would be larger and more numerous in the rabbit feces. I've never noticed worms before a pet ingests them, but they are much more noticeable after. Even if not noticeable, this would still be my guess.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: surely you'd browse for a rather specific subset of forage? I mean, not grasses but maybe only their seeds, and particular green plants (the so-called edible ones).